# Tkinter app crash when pynput keyboard listener start

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, listener, pynput

I have a problem that I can't deal with for a week...
When I start pynput keyboard listener from tkinter button command on macOS like in example below, app crashes only with "Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)" message in console. On Windows 11 everything works fine. I tried starting the listener from a new thread but that's the same.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from pynput import keyboard

logo = b'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'

root = Tk()
root.title("Test window")
root.geometry("400x200")
core_logo_icon = tkinter.PhotoImage(data=logo)


def start_listener():
    def on_press(key):
        print("Key ", key, " pressed")

    def on_release(key):
        print("Key ", key, " released")

    keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
    keyboard_listener.start()
    print("Keyboard listener ON")


button = Button(root, command=start_listener, image=core_logo_icon, borderwidth=0)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm using pynput 1.7.6, Python 3.9 on macOS Monterey 12.4 M1 PRO. Thank you for any help.

Edit: When I run app from terminal, err msg is "zsh: trace trap path/to/py/script"