# Why does this combination of tkinter and pynput crash python on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pynput

I am working on a Python customtkinter application that is meant to capture keystrokes, which will be used as a macro. The pynput code to capture keystrokes works fine without tkinter, and the code below works fine on Windows, but it reliably crashes python under macOS. It crashes on Intel and M2 CPUs, on different versions of python, and under Sonoma and Ventura.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/jasonluther/open-deck/blob/macos-key-recording/Code/Python/src/opendeckmanager/issue.py) application that triggers the problem:

```py
import tkinter
import threading
from pynput import keyboard


class KeyRecorder:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.listener = None
        self.callback = None
        self.macro = []

    def record(self, seconds, callback):
        self.callback = callback
        self.macro.clear()

        def on_press(key):
            self.macro.append(('press', key))
            return True

        def on_release(key):
            self.macro.append(('release', key))
            return True

        def end_recording():
            self.listener.stop()
            self.callback(self.macro)

        self.listener = keyboard.Listener(
            on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
        self.listener.start()

        timer = threading.Timer(seconds, end_recording)
        timer.start()

key_recorder = KeyRecorder()


def record():
    def handle_recording(keys):
        print(f"Callback called: {keys}")

    key_recorder.record(5, handle_recording)


app = tkinter.Tk()

button = tkinter.Button(command=record, text="Record")
button.pack(pady=20)

app.mainloop()
```

The application that runs this code has been granted the necessary macOS permissions (Accessibility, Input Monitoring).

I see some issue reports at https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/511 and https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/366 that look related, but I don't really fully understand them. There is a similar unanswered question here: [Tkinter app crash when pynput keyboard listener start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72853393/tkinter-app-crash-when-pynput-keyboard-listener-start).

I have read that there are problems updating tkinter elements from a different thread than the main thread that runs the tkinter mainloop, but I don't think that's applicable with the code above.

Is there something wrong with this code, and it just happens to work under Windows? Or am I doing something that should work, but I'm hitting a bug in pynput, macOS, or python?

Here's a snippet of Apple's *Problem Report for Python* showing the calls leading to the crash in the thread:

```
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18876fd0c _dispatch_assert_queue_fail + 120
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18876fc94 dispatch_assert_queue + 196
2   HIToolbox                              0x192f50b08 islGetInputSourceListWithAdditions + 160
3   HIToolbox                              0x192f53144 isValidateInputSourceRef + 92
4   HIToolbox                              0x192f53004 TSMGetInputSourceProperty + 44
5   libffi.dylib                           0x1993ff050 ffi_call_SYSV + 80
6   libffi.dylib                           0x199407adc ffi_call_int + 1208
7   _ctypes.cpython-312-darwin.so          0x104f5f3c8 _ctypes_callproc + 1384
8   _ctypes.cpython-312-darwin.so          0x104f572c4 PyCFuncPtr_call + 212
9   Python                                 0x1023f4ecc _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 128
10  Python                                 0x1025663f0 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 47712
11  Python                                 0x1024179e8 gen_send_ex2 + 196
12  Python                                 0x102415cc8 gen_iternext + 36
13  Python                                 0x102557bcc builtin_next + 76
14  Python                                 0x102463774 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 96
15  Python                                 0x10256628c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 47356
16  Python                                 0x1023f8fdc method_vectorcall + 368
17  Python                                 0x102565b3c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45484
18  Python                                 0x1023f8fdc method_vectorcall + 368
19  Python                                 0x10267da84 thread_run + 92
20  Python                                 0x1025ef8fc pythread_wrapper + 48
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18891b034 _pthread_start + 136
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x188915e3c thread_start + 8
```

Comment: If you run above script standalone, does it crash ?

Comment: Under macOS, the script will run until you click the button, which triggers a call to keyboard.Listener().start(), and that's what ultimately triggers the python crash.

Comment: Does this help? https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/

Comment: @toyotaSupra: thanks, but it does not change the behavior.

Comment: Did you find a fix? I'm using GTK and having the same problem, the code works fine without the gtk but as soon as I use it, python crashes.

Comment: @PauloMesquita: Unfortunately, I never found a fix. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue is keyboard.Listener gets started in buntton's command.

Consider this :

```
import tkinter
import threading
from pynput import keyboard

state = 0
class KeyRecorder:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.callback = None
        self.macro = []
        def on_press(key):
            if state == 1:
                self.macro.append(('press', key))
            return True

        def on_release(key):
            if state == 1:
                self.macro.append(('release', key))
            return True

        self.listener = keyboard.Listener(
            on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
        self.listener.start()

    def record(self, seconds, callback):
        self.callback = callback
        self.macro.clear()

        def end_recording():
            global state
            state = 0
            # self.listener.stop()
            self.callback(self.macro)

        global state
        state = 1
        timer = threading.Timer(seconds, end_recording)
        timer.start()

key_recorder = KeyRecorder()


def record():
    def handle_recording(keys):
        print(f"Callback called: {keys}")

    key_recorder.record(5, handle_recording)


app = tkinter.Tk()

button = tkinter.Button(command=record, text="Record")
button.pack(pady=20)

app.mainloop()
```

This is another version using multiprocessing :

```
import tkinter
from pynput import keyboard
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue, Event
import time

def get_event(q, stop_event):
    def on_press(key):
        q.put(f"{key} pressed")
        return True
    def on_release(key):
        q.put(f"{key} released")
        return True
    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
    listener.start()
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        time.sleep(0.100)
    listener.stop()

def worker(q, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set() or not q.empty():
        item = q.get()
        print(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    stop_event = Event()

    worker_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(q, stop_event))
    worker_process.start()

    app = tkinter.Tk()

    def start_recording():
        global record_process
        if record_process is None or not record_process.is_alive():
            record_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_event, args=(q, stop_event))
            record_process.start()

    record_process = None
    button = tkinter.Button(app, command=start_recording, text="Record")
    button.pack(pady=20)

    app.mainloop()

    stop_event.set()
    if record_process is not None:
        record_process.join()
    worker_process.terminate()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. The downside to this approach is that the app is always handling keystrokes, even if if it's not recording them, but I'll see if I can incorporate something like this into the app.

Comment: I tried a different approach here: https://github.com/jasonluther/open-deck/blob/macos-key-recording/Code/Python/src/opendeckmanager/issue-different-thread.py. It still crashes python.

Comment: @JasonLuther Could you test the second solution which handles keystrokes after clicking the button.

Comment: Thanks! As written, the code will record until the app is closed. That seems to work.

I also tried adding `time.sleep(10)` and then `stop_event.set()` to the end of start_recording(). That sort of works. The first time, it works fine. Subsequent presses of the button don't work as well: on the next run, it captured only one keystroke, and then it stopped capturing at all.